# API fetching and error handling in NextJs 14

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, error-handling

I need guidance on how to gracefully display errors to end users when fetching data in Next.js. I'm using Next.js 14, and every time an error occurs, it gives me the following message. Is this a good way to display server errors?

> **An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.**

I'm throwing errors like below. Is there a better way to handle them?

```
try {
    const res = await fetch(APIURL, APIHeaders);

    const error = errorMessage + ' \nStatus: ' + res.status;

    // Check if the response is ok
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }

    // Check if the response is in JSON format.
    const contentType = res.headers.get('Content-Type');
    if (!contentType || !contentType.includes('application/json')) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }

    const data = await res.json();
    return data;
} catch (error: any) {
    console.log(
      '\x1b[41mURL:' + APIURL + '\nError:' + error.message + '\x1b[0m'
    );
    throw new Error(error.message);
}
```

Could anyone please help me to setup the error.tsx effectively?

Comment: Are calling this function on the client-side (useEffect) or on the server-side  (getStaticProps, getStaticProps)

Comment: @Hilory I'm fetching it in server side using Promise.all